# python script to SSH into remote computer and run command

Tags: python-3.x

i'm new to python3 and scripting. I've got 2 commands I need to write a script for. what i'm looking to do is ssh into a remote computer and run a command.

i've tested it manually and works fine but i'd need to put it in a script. Thanks for any help in advance.

1. `sshpass -p 'SecretPassword' ssh user@10.X.X.X`
2. `run a local command on remote computer`

Bartibog

Comment: this is what i have come up with so far, looks like i can connect but the command doesn't seem to run on the remote host

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko

try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 

    client.connect("10.0.0.0", port="22", username="MyUsername", password="MyPassword")

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("svt-shutdown-safe")
    
finally:
    client.close()

print ("done.")

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61230697/edit) your code into your question. It is unreadable in a comment.